# using onmouseover to call a function

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I have circles on my webpage by the id `circle`. Now, what I want is when the mouse hovers over the circle, a message should be displayed. 
Here's my code in javascript file:

```
document.getElementById("circle").onmouseover=function(){
    var information = document.getElementById("toast");
    message = "hello";
    if (alert == null){
            var toastHTML = '<div id="toast">' + message + '</div>';
            document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', toastHTML);
        }
    else
        information.style.opacity = 0.9;
    intervalCounter = setInterval("hideToast",1000);
};
```

But there seems to be some error, the javascript terminal gives:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmouseover' of null
```

Comment: `cicrle` should be `circle` ? or thats a typo??

Comment: Correct the spelling of "circle" in the first line of your code. Also, I'm not sure this will capture multiple elements with the same id. Maybe put a class on them and use jQuery's class selector to get the circles?

Comment: Could you show the HTML please? It would seem at first glance that document.getElementById('circle') is not finding an element.

Comment: You have 'circles' (plural?) on your page sharing an `id`? An `id` must be unique (though it should still return the *first* element found with a given `id`), so the typo seems quite likely to be your problem.

Comment: NOTE: Do ***not*** pass strings to `setInterval`, it uses `eval` (which is `evil`).  Pass functions: `setInterval(hideToast, 1000);`.

Comment: I solved it by using: document.getElementById("box") instead of the var box that I had specified

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in `onload` event like

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("cicrle").onmouseover=function(){
        // code goes here
    };
};
```